# Dell U2515H Daisy chaining with Palit GTX580 3GB

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, nvidia-geforce

I bought 2 U2515H and connected the first panel via Display Port with the graphics card. Then I connected the first panel with the second one. It doesn't work. Only panel one, which is connected directly with the card is working. Now I am not sure, if daisy chaining will work. It is possible to connect the second monitor via HDMI cable, but this will result in not getting full native resolution of the screen. Does someone know which DSP version is supported by GTX580? Maybe it is not 1.2 as it is requested by Dell. Maybe someone is using the same configuration (which works). Glad for any help.

Comment: display port capability would be built by the graphics card manufacturer, not the GTX580 chipset itself, but I'd take a guess that the 580 [2010] is too old to have DP1.3 [2014] which would be needed for MST.

Comment: @Tetsujin isn't DP1.2 enough for using MST? The manual says it.

Comment: Wikipedia says 1.3 - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort

Answer (score 0):

In order do daisy chain display port monitors you need display port version 1.3 with MST support. Both on the card and at least in the middle monitor. (I suspect also on the last monitors, but I am not 100% sure of that).

Now your monitors are fine. They support it. But your graphics card is older. ITs [specification](http://www.palit.com/palit/vgapro.php?id=1503&lang=en&pn=NE5X580010FB-1100F&tab=sp) meantion it has DP, but not which versions. That is a bad thing since most modern cards with DP 1.3 support will happyily declare that on their specs page.

Your card is also a bit order. Its manual was updated in 2015, Its PCI-E interface is 2.0... That is almost the same time when displayport 1.3 was approved. Yet your cards was very likely designed and manufacturered before that date.

That leaves you these options:

1. Get a modern graphics card with atleast DP 1.3 and MST.
   Looks cleanest with fewer cable going ot the desktop. But it does share the bandwidth over one cable.
2. Or connect each monitor to its own DP port on a graphics card.
3. Or use sub par HDMI.

Since two identical monitors work best with identical resolutions (at least it does for me), I would either get a cheap second graphics card with an DP out, or I would upgrade to something slightly more modern.